# Change attribute in very big XML without loading it all

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a very big XML file ~200Mb.

I need to update some attributes inside it, and i want to do this without using any `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` libraries, because they require loading the entire document in memory.

What is the easiest and most efficient way to do this?

I am even thinking of modifying the xml using native string manipulation, but i will lose the XML specific features.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `XmlReader` & `XmlWriter` combination: read each token in your file step-by-step with `XmlReader` and then pass (modify if needed) it to the `XmlWriter`